# AWS IAM / QuickSight - user is not authorized to perform: quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to use the embed QuickSight dashboard URL function in my ASP.NET MVC project. For testing, I'm simply trying to output the embed URL to a string. Here is the main part of my code:

```
    var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("redacted", "redacted");

    AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(awsCredentials);
    var tokenServiceRequest = stsClient.GetSessionToken();

    var client = new AmazonQuickSightClient(
        tokenServiceRequest.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        tokenServiceRequest.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        tokenServiceRequest.Credentials.SessionToken,
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
    try
    {
        string machineTypeEmbedUrl =
            client.GetDashboardEmbedUrlAsync(new GetDashboardEmbedUrlRequest
            {
                AwsAccountId = "redacted",
                DashboardId = "redacted",
                IdentityType = IdentityType.IAM,
                ResetDisabled = true,
                SessionLifetimeInMinutes = 100,
                UndoRedoDisabled = false
            }).Result.EmbedUrl;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,ex.Message);
    }
```

In order to support the permissions required, I have set up an IAM user with the STS Assume Role allowed as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1551593192075",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/assume-quicksight-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have set up the role specified above with the following permissions, and set its trust policy so that the IAM user above can assume it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:RegisterUser",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:redacted:dashboard/redacted",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

So as far as I can tell this should work. Debug reveals I do get a session token which is passed to the embedUrl request, however I get the following error:

> InnerException = {"User:
>   arn:aws:iam:::user/api-dev-quicksight-user is not authorized
>   to perform: quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl on resource:
>   arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2::dashboard/"}

I'm not sure why this happens? I have a user that can assume the right role, and the role has the right permissions to the dashboard in question. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your role like this (notice the `::` double colon before `dashboard`):

```
...
"Action": "quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl", 
"Resource": "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2::dashboard/*", 
"Effect": "Allow"
...
```

This should allow the user to access all the sub-resources under the dashboard.

To follow the [Least Privilege principle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) recommend by AWS, you should list all your resources:

```
...
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2::dashboard/", 
    "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2::dashboard/redacted"]
...
```

Comment: Hi Barney, I tried your first suggestion of removing the account and adding the asterix to the end, but it's the same error -User: arn:aws:iam::redacted:user/api-dev-quicksight-user is not authorized to perform: quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl on resource: arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:redacted:dashboard/redacted_dashboard_id

Comment: Interestingly while editing the role, AWS Console tells me that GetDashboardEmbedUrl isn't recognised? - IAM does not recognize one or more actions. The action name might include a typo or might be part of a previewed or custom service

Comment: Actually, the error is different now. It says `redacted_dashboard_id` is not accessible now. Try to add the correct resource to the list. Or you can set the role resources to `arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:redacted:*` (notice the asterisk in the end).

Comment: Something is 'off' I set resource to '*' and it is STILL the exact same error. Maybe I've stuffed something up in my IAM User / Trust relationship / IAM Role / IAM Policy (for QuickSight) but I think it's all as it should be :/ Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure, the role is correctly assigned to the user? Try to give him the full access (action: *, resources: *) and see what happens.

Comment: I'll have to fiddle with it tomorrow, it's late here.. but I'm not giving the user direct access to QuickSight, as the QuickSight SDK requires that you pass a session token in as authentication, so that means you need to use the model where an IAM user assumes the role via STS, so you get a session token to pass to the QuickSight client (see code snippet in my question).. so technically the IAM user only has permissions to assume the role, but the role DOES have the right permissions, at least as far as the AWS tutorial is concerned...

Comment: I'm still getting User: arn:aws:iam::....:user/api-dev-quicksight-user is not authorized to perform: quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl on resource: arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:.......:dashboard/........  and that's after setting the policy for the assumed role to             "Action": "quicksight:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"

Comment: So I seem to have stuffed up in how I'm getting the IAM user to assume the role that has the required permissions as when I add Administrator to the User, it works (in so far as I now get the error that you can only embed dashboards on enterprise). So looks like I need to go back to the study board as to how to get an IAM user to assume a role!

Comment: JamesMatson - Have you found a solution to this yet? I am running into the same issue. I am trying to programmatically get the embedded dashboard url for a given user. Here are the steps I am doing:

  1. Register the user using the QuickSight client
  2. Add the user to a QuickSight group that has access to the dashboard
  3. Use STS to assume the role of the new user
  4. Instantiate a new QuickSight client with the access key, secret key and session token
  5. Get the embedded dashboard url

But I always get the same error specified above and its driving me crazy!